Compare modeling result and experiment data - different sampling rate?
My goal is to compare two voltage curves in python: One obtained by running simulation with PyBAMM/PyBOP and one is extracted from real measurement, recorded by a battery cycler BaSyTec. In the end I have two data sets:
simulation = {'Time [s]' : time_sim, 'Voltage [V]' : voltage_sim}
experiment = {'Time [s]' : time_measurement, 'Voltage [V]' : voltage_measurement}
My problem is, len(time_sim) ≠ len(time_measurement) and time_measurement is not linear. I'm having a hard time try to calculate RMSE Error for the two curves. I tried interpolate time_measurement so that it has the same length as time_sim but because of the non-linearity, I didn't succeed.
Here's how the two time stamps look:
Comparision Time Stamps
Any hints how should I approach to compare voltage_sim vs. voltage_measurement in a meaningful way?
Expectation: I should be able to calculate the differences / RMSE Error between voltage_sim and voltage_measurement to evaluate if my model yields a realistic voltage curve

Welcome to Stack Overflow.. For us to help you, provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.
DO NOT post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.
